# How to Create Event Based in Microstrategy on database Query?

Tags: microstrategy

I want to create a event (event based trigger) in Microstrategy based on database query.
I want to trigger that event on particular dates that i have in my database Table,How should i do that?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be
Create a unix/windows batch script containing sql query which looks if current date= date stored and execute a command manager script(micorstrategy) if condition is satisfied